# Can i add subscribe button to a facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I want to subscribe to a facebook page for example with this url ,http://www.myurl.com

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/subscribe.php?href=http://www.myurl.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;width=450&amp;appId=355223321210852" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When i am doing this the it gives me an error like it can be added to user profile only.
How can i have a subscribe button to a page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscribe button has to point to a Facebook profile URL; therefore `http://myurl.com` will not work. See an example here for one that works and one that doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/6jaP2/

Comment: I tried with the following url http://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/pageid but still does not work . It returns me an error message "The `href` parameter must reference a valid Facebook user profile, but "http://www.facebook.com/pages/page/pageid" is not a valid Facebook user profile. "

Comment: what is the url you are using?

Comment: Here is the iframe i am using <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/subscribe.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmvbpage&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;width=450&amp;appId=355223321210852" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>            and it returns me with an error http://jsfiddle.net/6jaP2/1/

Comment: You can only subscribe to users. You can't subscribe to pages.